# traefik failed external connectivity - 443 already in use

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

I am running a server and I have a pointed my domain via cloudflare to my server IP and have a signed SSL certificate via LetsEncrypt for my domain. My server is running an apache webserver using porto 443 for the ssl traffic.
I installed docker and a run a couple of containers. My goal is to get traefik up and running using port 443 as well and route all docker traffic through it. Is that even possible?

I used this here: https://www.linuxserver.io/2018/02/03/using-traefik-as-a-reverse-proxy-with-docker/ to write my traefik.toml file and my docker-compose file.

However, whenever I start up the docker-compose all services are up except traefik.
I receive following error:

> ERROR: for traefik  Cannot start service traefik: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint traefik (2d10b64b47e62e7dcb5f94265529fb647e4ba62dbeeb43c201ea02d39f60b381): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:443: bind: address already in use
>   ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

I wonder if the reason is that I already use port 443 for my domain?!
How can I fix this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are using docker in Linux:

Some of these commands should give you a clue that you are using them:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN

netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

example:

> docker-pr  2405            root    4u  IPv6   28930      0t0  TCP
>   *:443 (LISTEN)

if 443 is occupied by docker ... it means that you have in some YML an exposed port 443, besides that of Traefik (if it is some other application proceeds to change port or close it [pkill])

You can try to separate the "Services" of the YML in different YML and turn them on one by one, in order to find the image that is causing you conflicts
(If you separate them remember to create the appropriate external "[Networks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)".)

(by the way ... I recommend that the first image that starts be the one of traefik)

(You can also copy and paste your YML files for better help.)

Edit

---

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
# RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^9000$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}:9443%{REQUEST_URI}
```

edit2 in toml config traefik:  (I have no idea what works, try it)

---

```
# Entrypoints, http and https
[entryPoints]

# http should be redirected to https
[entryPoints.http]
address = ":80"
[entryPoints.http.redirect]
entryPoint = "https"

# https is the default
[entryPoints.https]
address = ":9443"

[entryPoints.https.tls]
```

---

The other solution that occurs to me is to make your main apache as a Proxy Tunnel, BUT, then you do not need to bring traefik :P

Comment: Hi nasatome,
thanks for your quick response. No other docker container is exposed to port 443. Instead my apache2 on the host machine is listening to port 443 so that my main domain can be reached using that port. I was wondering if I can make traefik using either the same domain or another one.

Comment: You have two solutions according to my point of view:
1.- Move your apache from the host to a docker image and now bringfik takes care of traffic management (ideal)
2.- move your apache host ...to another port; example in edit:

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue.
I've tried everything I found on stackoverflow and github.

***Only this worked for me***:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

And I've got somethink like this:

[image]

And I decided to ***kill the first PID*** (related to ***80 port***)

```
sudo kill -9 1876
```

And then I've started the service with docker on network and everything worked fine. Hooray!!!